# Nodejs typescript testing dependency

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, jestjs

I want to be able to test a Robot instantiated in a unit test that imports a Grid instantiated from another file: Controller.ts.

The thing is that the controller endpoint that creates that grid works because it'll create a Grid instance and export it so the Robot class can use it after. But that's not the case in the unit tests.

Here's the code:

Robot.ts

```js
import { grid } from "./controller";

class Robot {
    
    constructor(public x, public y, public orientation) {}

    move(){
        if (grid.isOffGrid(x, y)) {

        }
    }
}
```

Controller.ts

```js
export let grid = null;

router.post("/", bodyParser, (req, res, next) => {
    // some code

    grid = new Grid(5, 4);

}
```

Robot.test.ts

```js
import Robot from "./Robot";

describe("Robot", () => {
  it("should position robot on grid", () => {
    const x = 0;
    const y = 1;
    const orientation = "N";
    const robot = new Robot(x, y, orientation);
  })
})
```

When I try to run `npm test` I get the following message:

`Cannot read property 'isOffGrid' of undefined`

```js
    if (grid.isOffGrid(x, y)) {
      // more code
    }
```

How can I import in Robot.ts the Grid instantiated in the tests instead of importing the { grid } from Controller.ts ? Is there another approach?

Comment: Your difficulty in testing is telling you the code has issues. It seems like you're writing a web app using in-memory global state, which isn't a good idea.

Comment: what's the solution then @jonrsharpe ?